# C# Method to check if an Active Directory Domain Controller is up and running

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'd like to enhance a C# program I'm writing so that it can leverage any one of a list of Global Catalog DCs should one or more of them be offline.  I would like to write a method that returns a bool value depending upon whether or not ADDS is operational on the target server (not just whether the server is pingable):

```
public bool DC_is_Alive(string DomainControllerFQDN) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: this page may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267453.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#sdsadintro_topic3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use one of the following approaches:

I. Create DirectoryEntry to RootDSE partition on the server, catch COMException and check error code

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://serverFqdn/RootDSE"))
{
    entry.RefreshCache();
}
```

II. Create LdapConnection to the server, call Bind method, catch LdapException and check error code

```
using (var connection = new LdapConnection...)
{
    connection.Bind();
}
```

III. Call DomainController.GetDomainController method, and catch the ActiveDirectoryObjectNotFoundException

```
var dc = DomainController.GetDomainController(new DirectoryContext...);
```

P. S. From my experience, DomainController.GetDomainController may hang, so the the entire program stops responding (it happens in 1 AD environment out of 1000). Created a version of method, which calls DomainController.GetDomainController asynchronously and throws TimeoutException in case of hanging

Comment: Wonderful!  This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.  Thanks very much!

Comment: How would you do the above with DomainController.GetDomainController asynchronously, can someone show a code example using var dc = DomainController.GetDomainController(new DirectoryContext... then throwing the exception?